# Accessing javascript array from onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using jQuery and populating an array on document.ready.

In my page I have some elements with a click event.  I defined that function outside of the document.ready function.

I can't seem to figure out how to access that array variable from within my onclick function.

To simplify, I would like something like this to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var artists = new Array();
  artists.push('item1');
  artists.push('item2');
});

function clickLink() {
  alert(artists[0]);
}
```

Comment: Read up on what `var` does. Why does this prevent `artists` from being accessed (much less, existing) in the other function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways, one of the easiest, move your click hander inside the .ready() function. And you need to bind it to the element there instead of inline attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var artists = new Array();
  artists.push('item1');
  artists.push('item2');

  $('#idOfTheElement').click(function() {
    alert(artists[0]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

hi you lost scope of creation of array, so there is two ways to solve it

Put all in same scope:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var artists = new Array();
      artists.push('item1');
      artists.push('item2');
    function clickLink() {
      alert(artists[0]);
    }
    });
```

Declare array as global:

```
var artists = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){

      artists.push('item1');
      artists.push('item2');

    });
function clickLink() {
      alert(artists[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the `artists` array outside the `document.ready()` function and bind the function with the click event.

```js
var artists = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
  artists.push('item1');
  artists.push('item2');
});

$('button').click(function() {
  console.log(artists[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to remove the var keyword when you declare the array variable, which will make the variable global and that is not recommended and another solution would be to declare your array outside the function so that it can be referenced from onclick function.